# Transformar una propiedad dentro de un Schema en mongoose

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, mongoose

Estoy haciendo unos modelos para una aplicación, necesito transformar un nombre en una especie de liga cannon. Este es el modelo

```
import mongo from 'mongoose'

const schema = new mongo.Schema({
    name: { 
        type: String, 
        required:  [true, 'El nombre de la marca es necesaria' ],
        unique:    [true, 'Ya existe esta marca'],
        minlength: [3, 'Al menos 3 caracteres'],
        maxlength: [100, 'Máximo 100 caracteres'],
    },
    link: { 
        type: String,
        default: function() {
            return this.name
            .normalize("NFD")
            .replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "")
            .replace(/\s+/g, '-')
            .toLowerCase()
        }
    },
    active: { type: Boolean, default: true }

}, { collection: 'moto-brands' })

export const MotoBrandModel = mongo.model( 'MotoBrand', schema )
```

A este punto Typescript me empieza a marcar un error, por ende el servidor truena con el mismo error. El error me lo marca en `this.name` Este es el error

> Property 'name' does not exist on type 'SchemaTypeOpts |
>   Schema | SchemaType'.
>
> Property 'name' does not exist on type 'SchemaTypeOpts'

Lo que debe hacer esa función como ya mencioné es hacer una liga canónica para el navegador, me explico.

Cuando al end point llegue 
la propiedad `name`

con valor `El Pingüino maléfico`

este deberá ser transformado a `el-pinguino-malefico` y asignado al índice `link` del schema.

En fin, la función trabaja perfecto, no tengo problema con ella, el problema es que no puedo acceder a la propiedad name del mismo objeto.

¿Se les ocurre algo?

Comment: Hola Alberto, has probado ver que es lo que te muestra `this` cuando entra en la función? Sino podrías utilizar el método [`SchemaType.prototype.get()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/schematype.html#schematype_SchemaType-get) de mongoose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes lograrlo usando un [`pre Hook`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema-pre). El cual se ejecutará justo antes de realizar el proceso de inserción en la base de datos.

De esta forma no importa el valor que tenga `link` al momento de crear el documento, ya que el mismo será sobreescrito (o creado si no existe) al ejecutarse la función pasada al método `pre` de tu esquema.

Por ejemplo:

```js
import mongo from 'mongoose'

const schema = new mongo.Schema({
    name: { 
        type: String, 
        required:  [true, 'El nombre de la marca es necesaria' ],
        unique:    [true, 'Ya existe esta marca'],
        minlength: [3, 'Al menos 3 caracteres'],
        maxlength: [100, 'Máximo 100 caracteres'],
    },
    link: { 
        type: String,
        default: '' // <= podemos poner un valor por defecto o no
    },
    active: { type: Boolean, default: true }

}, { collection: 'moto-brands' });

// creamos la función que será ejecutada como pre hook
const buildLink = function(next) {
  this.link = this.name
    .normalize("NFD")
    .replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "")
    .replace(/\s+/g, '-')
    .toLowerCase();
  return next();
}

// llamamos al método pre() para el evento 'save'
schema.pre('save', buildLink);

export const MotoBrandModel = mongo.model( 'MotoBrand', schema );
```

Cada vez que salvemos un documento creado a partir del modelo, se ejecutará nuestro método para construir el campo `link`.

Por ejemplo:

```js
async () => {
  // creamos un nuevo documento, notese que no paso el valor del campo link
  let moto = new MotoBrandModel({name: 'The Return of the Jedi'});
  let motoSaved = await moto.save();
  console.log(motoSaved);
}
```

El resultado del proceso descrito se debe ver parecido a lo siguiente:

```js
{
  active: true,
  _id: 5de7e430f6b58149dfadc822,
  name: 'The Return of the Jedi',
  link: 'the-return-of-the-jedi',
  __v: 0
}
```

Con esto ya tienes una forma de lograr lo que te propones.

Comment: ¡Que trucazo sensei! Gracias.